# Exclude rows where dates exist in another table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have 2 tables, one is working pattern, another is absences.

1) Work pattern

```
ID | Shift Start | Shift End
123| 01-03-2017  | 02-03-2017
```

2) Absences

```
ID| Absence Start | Absence End
123| 01-03-2017   | 04-03-2017
```

What would be the best way, when selecting rows from work pattern, to exclude any that have a date marked as an absence in the absence table?

For example, I have a report that uses the work pattern table to count how may days a week an employee has worked, however I don't want it to include the days that have been marked as an absence on the absence table if that makes sense? Also don't want it to include any days that fall between the absence start and absence end date?

Comment: Are those long or short date ranges? [xkcd PSA ISO 8601](https://xkcd.com/1179/) -- I noticed that every date you have used makes the date format ambiguous.

Comment: Does absences.id relate to WorkPattern.id?

Comment: Sorry, these are short date ranges. Just an example.

Comment: Yes it does relate to workpattern.id

Comment: So there can be numerous records with ID 123 in the absences table which would show multiple absence periods for one employee?

Comment: How are you calculating the number of work days?

Comment: You need to be able to determine which days are non-working days, such as weekends and holidays. Especially the holidays, since each business may have different holiday schedules. Again, I'll echo my suggestion that a calendar table should be requested.

Comment: And what RDBMS?

Comment: Looking at the data, Work Pattern is the scheduled shift and Absences is the actual recorded information, correct? So if an ID doesn't have an Absense row, then they worked their shift? And both of these will be a range?

Answer (score 5):

If the span of the `absence` should always encompass the shift to be excluded you can use `not exists()`:

```
select *
from WorkPatterns w
where not exists (
  select 1
  from Absences a
  where a.Id = w.Id
    and a.AbsenceStart <= w.ShiftStart
    and a.AbsenceEnd   >= w.ShiftEnd
  )
```

rextester demo: http://rextester.com/DCODC76816

returns:

```
+-----+------------+------------+
| id  | ShiftStart |  ShiftEnd  |
+-----+------------+------------+
| 123 | 2017-02-27 | 2017-02-28 |
| 123 | 2017-03-05 | 2017-03-06 |
+-----+------------+------------+
```

given this test setup:

```
create table WorkPatterns ([id] int, [ShiftStart] datetime, [ShiftEnd] datetime) ; 
insert into WorkPatterns ([id], [ShiftStart], [ShiftEnd]) values 
 (123, '20170227', '20170228')
,(123, '20170301', '20170302')
,(123, '20170303', '20170304')
,(123, '20170305', '20170306')
;
create table Absences ([id] int, [AbsenceStart] datetime, [AbsenceEnd] datetime) ; 
insert into Absences ([id], [AbsenceStart], [AbsenceEnd]) values 
(123, '20170301', '20170304');
```

Comment: Thank you!

One more question - Is it possible to do this for example, if someone only had an absence for half a day?

There are absence time start and an absence time end columns on the absence table - if an absence start time was 9am and the end time was 5pm - that would count as one full absence. If the absence start time was 12pm and the end time was 5pm that would count as a half day - so I would want my count to be something like 4.5 days worked (4 full days, 1 half day)

What would be the best way of going about this?

I appreciate all your help!

Comment: @jd0963 I recommend asking a new question with good (complete) example data and desired results; check out these links for some tips:
[How to post a tsql question on a public forum](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) and [How-to-Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1):

> What would be the best way, when selecting rows from work pattern

If you dealing only whit dates (no time) and have control over db schema,
One approach will be to create calendar table ,
Where you going to put all dates since company started and some years in future
Fill that table once. 
After it is easy to join other tables whit dates and do math.

If you have trouble whit constructing TSQL query please edit question whit more details about columns and values of tables, relations and needed results.

Comment: I don't have any control over tables etc, I can only query them.

Based on my example, I would want to see all working days for ID 123 where the shift start and shift end dates don't fall in the same date range in the absences table..so I can have an accurate count of actual days worked for this ID

Comment: I will echo adopilot here. A calendar table should be a part of every database. It will always ultimately be needed, and it makes life _SO_ much easier for everyone. I would beg your DBAs to add one.

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
SELECT WP_START.[id], WP_START.[shift_start], WP_START.[shift_end]
FROM work_pattern AS WP_START
INNER JOIN absences AS A ON WP_START.id = A.id 
WHERE WP_START.[shift_start] NOT BETWEEN A.[absence_start] AND A.[absence_end]

UNION

SELECT WP_END.[id], WP_END.[shift_start], WP_END.[shift_end]
FROM work_pattern AS WP_END
INNER JOIN absences AS A ON WP_END.id = A.id 
WHERE WP_END.[shift_end] NOT BETWEEN A.[absence_start] AND A.[absence_end]
```

See it on SQL Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/49ae6/6

Answer (score 0):

Here is my example that includes a Date Dimension table. If your DBAs won't add it, you *can* create #dateDim as a temp table, like I've done with SQLFiddle *(didn't know I could do that)*. A typical date dimension would have a lot more details you need about the days, but if the table can't be added, just use what you need. You'll have to populate the other Holidays you need. The DateDim I use often is at https://github.com/shawnoden/SQL_Stuff/blob/master/sql_CreateDateDimension.sql

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/8ce75/1)

**MS SQL Server 2014 Schema Setup**:

```
/* Tables for your test data. */
CREATE TABLE WorkPatterns ( id int, ShiftStart date, ShiftEnd date ) ;
INSERT INTO WorkPatterns ( id, ShiftStart, ShiftEnd )
VALUES
      (123, '20170101', '20171031')
    , (124, '20170601', '20170831')
;

CREATE TABLE Absences ( id int, AbsenceStart date, AbsenceEnd date ) ;
INSERT INTO Absences ( id, AbsenceStart, AbsenceEnd )
VALUES 
      ( 123, '20170123', '20170127' )
    , ( 123, '20170710', '20170831' )
    , ( 124, '20170801', '20170820' )
;

/* ******** MAKE SIMPLE CALENDAR TABLE ******** */

CREATE TABLE dateDim (
      theDate             DATE        NOT NULL
    , IsWeekend           BIT         DEFAULT 0
    , IsHoliday           BIT         DEFAULT 0
    , IsWorkDay           BIT         DEFAULT 0
);

/* Populate basic details of dates. */
INSERT dateDim(theDate, IsWeekend, IsHoliday) 
SELECT d
  , CONVERT(BIT, CASE WHEN DATEPART(dw,d) IN (1,7) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
  , CONVERT(BIT, CASE WHEN d = '20170704' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) /* 4th of July. */
FROM (
    SELECT d = DATEADD(DAY, rn - 1, '20170101')
    FROM 
    (
        SELECT TOP (DATEDIFF(DAY, '20170101', '20171231')) 
            rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY s1.[object_id])
        FROM sys.all_objects AS s1
        CROSS JOIN sys.all_objects AS s2
        ORDER BY s1.[object_id]
    ) AS x
) AS y ;

/* If not a weekend or holiday, it's a WorkDay. */
UPDATE dateDim 
SET IsWorkDay = CASE WHEN IsWeekend = 0 AND IsHoliday = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
;
```

**Query For Calculation**:

```
SELECT wp.ID, COUNT(d.theDate) AS workDayCount
FROM WorkPatterns wp
INNER JOIN dateDim d ON d.theDate BETWEEN wp.ShiftStart AND wp.ShiftEnd
  AND d.IsWorkDay = 1
LEFT OUTER JOIN Absences a ON d.theDate BETWEEN a.AbsenceStart AND a.AbsenceEnd
  AND wp.ID = a.ID
WHERE a.ID IS NULL
GROUP BY wp.ID
ORDER BY wp.ID
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/8ce75/1/0)**:

```
|  ID | workDayCount |
|-----|--------------|
| 123 |          172 |  << 216 total days, 44 non-working
| 124 |           51 |  <<  65 total days, 14 non-working
```